# What is Difference Between Policy Authorize vs Can Function In Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm using laravel basic policy system to protect unauthorized user from update post. For Example User have Id 1 and In posts Table **User_id** is also 1.

Now in `$this->authorize('update',$post);` way I can pass only one variable `$post` to authenticate. while in `can` method I can also use `$user` variable `$user->can('update',$post)` for authorize.

Here is code:

In PostPolicy.php :

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

In AuthServiceProvider.php :

```
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class
]
```

In Controller Authorize way :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post=Post::find(1);
    $user=User::find(1); 
    $this->authorize('update',$post);
    return 'Hello Everything Access For You ';
}
```

Using can method in Controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post=Post::find(1);
    $user=User::find(1); 
    if($user->can('update',$post)){
        return 'Your are allowed';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Your are Not allowed'; 
    }
}
```

Is I'm right for these two functions. Is there any Difference. Which method I have to use. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Per the docs, they're the same under the hood. User models have a `can` function. Controllers have an `authorize` one. Both use an underlying policy.

Comment: if they're the same under the hood then why i can not pass $user variable to     
 `$this->authorize('update',$user,$post)`

Comment: Because `authorize` is intended for authorizing [the current user](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.html#method_authorize).

Comment: but in some case i do not want to use current user. and use different user to check .try to understand  i love $this->authorize function but some gear missing .

Comment: That's what `can` is for. If you have any User model in `$user`, you do `$user->can()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using any of `authorize()` or `can()`, the purpose is to validate if user is authorized to do certain tasks.

But :

- In case of `authorize()`, if it fails(returns false from policy method),  the authorize method will throw an Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException, which the default Laravel exception handler will convert to an HTTP response with a 403
- In case of `can()`, it like just a basic method to check if user is authorized or not and then you need to handle the rest on your own. Like what to do if its unauthorized.

Considering above factors, I would say `$this->authorize('update',$post);` is easier to be used in controller.

Check more about the same in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies)

Also you can do :

`$request->user()->can()` if  you want to check authorization of current requesting user.

Update :

`authorize()` is designed to authorize current user who is logged in, where laravel passes current user automatically to policy.

Whereas you can use `can` on any user instance.

- `$request->user()->can()` if  you want to check authorization of current requesting user.
- `$user = $user::find($id); $user->can(...)` if its any other user

Comment: I know but can i pass $user variable to `$this->authorize('update',$user,$post)` ?

Comment: The user is automatically passed in by laravel in policy as the first argument. You do not need to pass it manually. :)

Comment: @Hashaamzahid The way of doing that (checking if a *specific* user instead of the *current* user has a permission) would be to find a user (something like `$user = App\User::find(123);`) and then to `$user->can()` on it.

Comment: but in different situation. try to understand please

Comment: @ceejayoz he is aleady doing that as per his question , isnt he?

Comment: @MihirBhende Essentially, although the sample code provided hard-codes user id #1.

Comment: There is no need to find(), he can do `$request->user()->can()`

Comment: @MihirBhende I get the impression OP wants to check authorization for someone *other than* the current user. A bit hard to tell, though; they're not being super clear.

Comment: Ahh I got what you meant! :)

Answer (score 4):

`$this->authorize()` checks if the **current user** is authorized. `$user->can()` checks if the user in `$user` is authorized. Both rely on the same underlying policy to make the decision.

The main difference between the two is that `$this->authorize()` throws an exception if the current user isn't authorized (as it's intended for use within a controller), whereas `$user->can()` just returns `true`/`false`.

If you want a controller to act as if it's doing `$this->authorize()` for a *different* user than the current one, you can do this:

```
// where "123" is the user you want to check against
$user = App\User::find(123);

if(!$user->can('update', $post) {
    throw new \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
}
```

That said, this is *rarely* what you want to do - it doesn't (usually) make much sense to determine if the current user can do something based on another user's permissions.